# "Git directory" and "working directory"

Tags: git, version-control

If I understood it correctly, ***Git directory*** is the hidden directoy named ***.git*** which resides in the ***working directory***. And all the code and history info is stored in the Git directory.

So I expected that when I clone some repo from GitHub, as shown below:

```
git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git .
```

I should just download the *.git* directory.

But there're plenty of other files in the *working directory* besides the hidden *.git directory*. I didn't expect to download other people's working directory.

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git automatically prepares the working directory for you by creating the files corresponding to the `master`  branch (or whatever you have configured as the default branch). It is not somebody else's working diretory. Its yours ;)

If you just want the bare `.git` folder, use `--bare` or `--mirror` keys.