# executing a git pull from a different directory

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm configuring [calimoucho](https://github.com/guillaumebort/calimoucho) (a little play continuos integration server), and for it to work I need to run a command to pull a cloned git hub repository from outside it.

to be more precise, I'll explain it with an example.

I have the following repository

```
cd /home/sas
mkdir apps
cd apps
mkdir myApp
cd myApp
git init
echo "my file" > file
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Just a silly test repository where my app is supossed to be

Now I need to clone that repository to a checkout folder.

```
cd /home/sas
mkdir calimoucho
cd calimoucho
mkdir checkout
cd checkout
git clone /home/sas/apps/myApp/
```

so I have the following directory structure

```
~/apps
    myapp
      .git
      file
~/calimoucho
    checkout
      myapp
        .git
        file
```

The continuos integration server will have to pull new changes from ~/apps/myapp to ~/calimoucho/checkout/myapp, running a command line sentence from ~/calimoucho

I try with the following command

```
~/calimoucho$ git --git-dir=/home/sas/apps/myApp/.git --work-tree=/home/sas/calimoucho/checkout/myApp/ pull
```

and I get the following error

```
fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

if I don't specify the --work-tree option, the pull is issued, but changes are applied to ~/calimoucho folder instead of ~/calimoucho/checkout/myApp

any idea how to update the cloned repo from the ~/calimoucho folder?

thanks a lot

Comment: already checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188314/git-directory-and-working-directory

Answer (score 137):

I had this question, too.  I found the answer in the git documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git).

Run the command

```
git -C <git-working-directory> pull <git remote>
```

The specific command to answer this question is

```
git -C checkout/myApp/ pull
```

Note that it is important `-C <git-working-directory>` comes before the `pull` command and any additional pull options can be specified at the end of the command.  In the example above, the `git clone` command would have setup the default remote repository ~/apps/myapp so it is not required to specify the remote repository.

Answer (score 16):

`git -C ~/Documents/blar/blar/directory/ pull`

This worked for me after hours of searching. I'm on a Mac in Terminal.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the answer already provided by @Danny.

Comment: same here, on Ubuntu 22, regular bash shell. No luck with `git-dir=`, instant sucess with `-C`

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me:

```
git --git-dir=/home/myuser/awesomeproject/.git --work-tree=/home/myuser/awesomeproject pull
```

I'm using it inside a post-update hook to automatically pull and restart pm2 on my test server.

Comment: `--git-dir` does more than that. `-C` is a better option.
From manual page for Git:
`If you just want to run git as if it was started in <path> then use git -C <path>.`

Comment: Hello, I voted several years ago for this post but when I reused this command I realized that it works differently. I use it in a git action my git head was updated however no files were changed I had to run a hard to get the changes in the . I think that dir should be used only if you are in the project folder but the .git is in another folder than this one

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this is only working solution:

```
git --git-dir=/gitbackup/test/.git pull
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. It will pull the changes into the `.git` but it will not overwrite and update the project files, which is the expected behaviour from a `git pull`. You will be left with a `git log` that shows the new commits, but a bunch of apparent uncommitted changes to the project directory, which are the old versions of the files that are diffed against the new commits.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the work-tree to a different repository than the git-dir variable. I think they are meant to be used when you don't want the .git folder to be in the same directory as your working tree. Instead try this:

```
~/calimoucho/$ git pull --work-tree=checkout/myApp/  ../../apps/myapp
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives: sas@test:~/calimoucho$ git pull ../apps
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git (tried also with ../apps/myApp, ../apps/myApp/.git)

Comment: ah! that's the problem, standing at the cloned repo folder everything works fine (in fact, a simple 'git pull' works ok)... the problem is how to do it from another folder...

Comment: Shouldn't the `--work-tree` come *before* the `pull` comand, like this: 
`git --work-tree=checkout/myApp/ pull ../../apps/myapp`

Answer (score 1):

In case your git version doesn't like the *git-working-directory* option:

> Unknown option: -C

Then use the *push-directory* command beforehand.

For example, this will pull your git project from parent directory (or clone if it doesn't exists):

```
pushd ./project-name && git pull && popd || git clone https://repo-url/project-name
```